# How to save Data from Parse to Local CoreData in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, parse-platform

So how can I save the data I got from Parse to a local CoreData in the app

This is the query I use to get the data from Parse:

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {

    let query = PFQuery(className: "News")
    query.cachePolicy = PFCachePolicy.NetworkElseCache
    query.orderByDescending("updatedAt")
    return query

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewsCell

    cell.NewsTitle.text = object?.objectForKey("NewsTitle") as? String 
    cell.NewsSubject.text = object?.objectForKey("NewsSubject") as? String


    let imagefile = object?.objectForKey("NewsImage") as? PFFile
  //  cell.NewsImage.image = UIImage(named: "News Title")
    cell.NewsImage.file = imagefile
    cell.NewsImage.loadInBackground()


    return cell


}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply use UserDefaults: (following example is for "newsTitle")

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
// Set newsTitle in NSUserDefaults
let temp = object?.objectForKey("NewsTitle") as? String
userDefaults.setValue(temp, forkey: "newsTitle")
userDefaults.synchronize()
// Get newsTitle in NSUserDefaults
cell.newsTitle.text = userDefaults.stringForKey("newsTitle")
```

If you have further questions, please feel free to ask.

****Update*****

```
getPicFromUser = userDefaults.dataForKey("userPic")
var image = UIImage()

if getPicFromUser != nil {
   image = UIImage(data: getPicFromUser!)!
} else {
   // no pic from nsdefaults
}
userPic.image = image
```

****Update*****

Comment: can i use NSUserDefaults with images to ?

Answer (score 0):

Just create your core data model with all objects you want to have (I also suggest to have a look at https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator for easy management of core data objects)), and create/modify/delete the objects in the core data model to sync them with the data you get from parse.